# java : Remote database disabled by administrator, is there another way to connect?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I used to connect my java app to a remote database ( MySQL ) through jdbc with: `url="jdbc:mysql://mydomain.com/myDataBase"`

But now, the remote database connexion has been disabled by the admin ( the hosting company )

Is there a way to connect to my database indirectly ? Like passing through a server side php script or something?

Comment: If you could un-disable remote access it wouldn't be disable.

Comment: @Peter: that would be nice, but then the word 'workaround' would have less meaning :)

Comment: @BalusC That might be a very bad idea. If the code is going to be used by the general public, this could be a huge security hole. The admin *was probably right to disable or firewall it*.

Comment: @Robin: No, that isn't a bad idea. Just communicate professionally. The admin can explain why it was disabled. The OP can just elaborate why he needs the DB. The admin might be able to suggest alternative URLs or to create a special login account. Etcetera. It's only a bad idea if the OP has bad intents (hacking/abusing the DB), but the OP has it fully in its hands.

Comment: @BalusC You assume the admin knows what he or she is doing, rather than just blindly following instructions.

Comment: @Robin: You assume that all admins are underdeveloped shrimps? ;)

Comment: @BalusC No. I'm sorry, I genuinely didn't mean to offend any admins who may be reading. I just know that incompetent admins *do exist* in the web hosting world.

Comment: Dedicated servers have more possibility/flexibility, but shared servers are much more restricted, I have also a host disabling connections except for PHP scripts hosted on the server. It is annoying because we cannot use tools like SQuirreL SQL Client or SchemaSpy on them. And there is no way to negotiate an access in such accounts.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a shell, there are two options worth looking into:

1. SSH Tunnel (for example, [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/))
2. [MySQLProxy](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/proxy-gettingstarted.html)

Comment: Oh my god, the admin has also disabled ssh ! they say security reasons ! what the hell is that for ?! it's like if they have an FBI database on the server or something !

Comment: is there a way to pass through server script php ? I know it's risky but I've got no choice

Comment: Hmm I guess you could get the sourcecode of MySQLProxy and rewrite it (or atleast its core functionality) in PHP... but if they restrict your PHP settings as well (for example max_execution_time) even that'll be a not-very-effective solution.

Comment: Can you do the inverse? Have their MySQL connect to one of your servers? Thinking of a remote table, federated, or a SLAVE...